# why is await not working even when used in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I made a function to search a user by email id. I'm calling that function in an async function using await and assigning the returned value to or constant/variable but getting undefined on printing the constant/variable

```
function search(email) {
    sql = `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '${email}'`;
    db.query(sql, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            return res[0].email;
        }
    })
}

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '');
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'catisdoguniversaltruth');
        const user = await search(decoded._id);
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        next();
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send("Not Authenticated, Please login");
    }
};

module.exports = auth;
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `search()` to be a promise and not a function.

`await` waits for a promise to resolve.

Try this:

```js
function search(email) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql = `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '${email}'`;
    db.query(sql, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(res[0].email);
      }
    })
  }) 
}
```

This will be resolved as promise and `auth()` will wait.

You could also build `search()` as `async/await` promise. Doesn't really matter as long as you return a promise resolve.

Comment: Though this answer will solve the problem, in case `db.query` api has an overload that returns a promise, simply returning `db.query(sql)` will also solve the problem.

Comment: @planet_hunter  Thanks for the addon.